# Best SELECT syntax performance with 5 parameter

Tags: sql-server

i trying to select a table which have a million records using a Stored Proc.
The Stored Proc have a 5 parameter.
Which is has the best performance

Query 1:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
WHERE Column1 like '%'+ @param1 +'%' AND
Column2 like '%'+ @param2 +'%' AND
Column3 like '%'+ @param3 +'%' AND
Column4 like '%'+ @param4 +'%' AND
Column5 like '%'+ @param5 +'%' AND
```

Note: I am using this because the result of LIKE with empty ('') param is the same as not using the param.

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
WHERE Column1 like '%'+ @param1 +'%'
```

is have the same result as

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
```

is the value of @param1 is empty ('')

Query 2:

```
IF @param1 = '' SELECT @param1 = null
IF @param2 = '' SELECT @param2 = null
IF @param3 = '' SELECT @param3 = null
IF @param4 = '' SELECT @param4 = null
IF @param5 = '' SELECT @param5 = null

IF @param1 is not null and @param2 is null and @param3 is null @param4 is null and @param5 is null
BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM Table1
  WHERE Column1 like '%'+ @param1 +'%'
END
```

and continue till all possibilities is covered.

Which is has the best performance?
The meaning of best is, has a efficient I/O and procession time
Thank you in advance

---

UPDATE

I've tried RADAR solution and i compared it with my first query using Actual Execution Plan
so it's the result:

Result from Query 1 (me)

[image]

Result from Query 2 (RADAR)

[image]

I don't know how to read it, please help me

Thanks again

Comment: Using `like '%' will prevent the use of index, so I suggest you stay away from this unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: because data in records is all in varchar. so it's necessary isn't it?

Comment: Depends, if you want to return string with `@param1` as substring then `like '%' + @param1 '%' is necessary. However, if you want only the exact match, better use `=`.

Comment: @user1008497, I just simplied your second approach with less code and made readable, both execution plans are same, try with some parameters as empty string and see the plan

Answer (score 1):

Second approach is better, you can simplify it with or condition based on parameter value

```
 SELECT * FROM Table1
 WHERE (@param1 ='' or Column1 like '%'+ @param1 +'%' )
 AND 
 (@param2 ='' or Column2 like '%'+ @param2 +'%' )
 AND...
```